# Unable to create sensor of type

Tags: gazebo-7

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I want to write a  Doppler Velocity Log (DVL) SensorPlugin for gazebo, but gazebo fails to load the plugin.
My DvlPlugin.cpp looks like this

```
#include "DvlPlugin.hpp"

using namespace std;
using namespace gazebo;

void DvlPlugin::Load(sensors::SensorPtr sensor, sdf::ElementPtr pluginElement){
    gzmsg << "Load" << endl;
}
```

and my DvlPlugin.hpp looks like this

```
#ifndef _GAZEBO_DVL_PLUGIN_HPP_
#define _GAZEBO_DVL_PLUGIN_HPP_
#include <gazebo/common/common.hh>
#include <gazebo/sensors/Sensor.hh>

namespace gazebo {
    class DvlPlugin : public gazebo::SensorPlugin
    {
    public:
        DvlPlugin(){}
        ~DvlPlugin(){}
        void Load(gazebo::sensors::SensorPtr sensor, sdf::ElementPtr sdf);
    };
    GZ_REGISTER_SENSOR_PLUGIN(DvlPlugin) 
}
#endif
```

So there is really nothing big that is done in the code, and everything compiles without errors. When I load following simple sdf file

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<sdf version="1.6">
    <world name="worl_test">
        <model name="model_test">
            <link name="link_test">
                <pose>0 0 0 0 0 0</pose>
                <inertial><mass>0.01</mass></inertial>
                <sensor type="dvl" name="dvl_test">
                    <plugin name="gazebo_dvl" filename="libgazebo_dvl.so"/>
                </sensor>
            </link>
        </model>
    </world>
</sdf>
```

I get the error **[Err] [SensorManager.cc:276] Unable to create sensor of type[dvl]** (which means, when we look the [SensorManager.cc code](https://github.com/arpg/Gazebo/blob/master/gazebo/sensors/SensorManager.cc), that the Sensor dvl is not in the SensorFactory. Do you have an Idea why I get this error?

PS: I am under Ubuntu 16.04 and I use gazebo 7.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/20324/unable-to-create-sensor-of-type/) by [Tekkk](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6382/tekkk/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 1 on 2018-08-28

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [wentz](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2629/wentz/) on 2018-08-31**:
Can you post your cmake file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

The error was, as the SensorManager says,  that there was not a sensor of type dvl. Since I wanted to make a sensorplugin, I must create an existing sensor (ray, contact etc.) and "extend" is. So here the solving of the error was simple: use `<sensor type="ray"` ...

---

Originally posted by [Tekkk](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6382/tekkk/) with karma: 1 on 2018-09-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0